# UITableViewCell Delete button screws up textLabel when using line break in text

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell`, when swipe to bring up the Delete button it screws up the textLabel because I am using a line break in text.

Before:

[image]

In delete mode:

[image]

This is frustrating because I just want the delete button to go over my text, rather than trying to animate it out of the way which screws it up.

- Why does this happen?  Because I use a line break in my string?
- How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen? Because I use a line break in my string?

It happends because you've added the label to the contentView of the cell (which is good). When the delete button appears the contentView will be automatically resized and the UITableViewCell's textLabel will resize as well because it's autoresizingMask is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`. Unfortunately we cannot override the autoresizingMask of the default textLabel.

> How can I prevent this from happening?

You'll have to build a custom cell yourself. Subclass UITableViewCell with a custom UILabel as a property and set it's autoresizingMask to `UIViewAutoresizingNone`.

```
//create and set your frame to whatever you want.
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 110, 20)];

//set autoresizing
[label setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];

//add to view
[[self contentView] addSubview:label];

//set property to acces later
[self myLabel:label];

//release (if you aren't using ARC)
[myLabel release];
```

add some sample text to test it later on

```
[[cell myLabel] setText:@"MAX: 72.92 MPH Will fit!"];
```

If you're using interfacebuilder to create your view/cells make sure the autoresizing mask arrow's are *grayed out*.

[image: interfacebuilder autoresizingMask]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the UITableViewCell's `textLabel.Frame` property. Subclass UITableViewCell and set this in `[UITableViewCell didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state]`

Comment: Ok, so set the frame in didTransitionToState?

Comment: He means save the old frame, and when you transition to the state== UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask, try to set the frame there. If this doesn't work I've got another idea, but this one might be easier for you (if it works)

Comment: No, that didn't seem to work. It just made things animate even stranger.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help - I'll pass off to someone who has done it before.